# How to expand this functions around 1

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have the following generating function:
$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{1 - xe^{1-x}}
$$
I'm trying to expand around 1. According to Wolframalpha:
$$
f(x) = \frac{2}{(1-x)^2} - \frac{4}{3(1-x)} + \frac{7}{18} + ...
$$

How do I find this result?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little trick that is useful in cases like yours:

First calculate the first non-zero term of the Taylor-expansion around $1$ of $1-xe^{1-x}$, which is proportional to $(x-1)^2$. 
Now determine the Taylor-expansion of

$\frac{(x-1)^2}{(1-xe^{1-x})}$,

which is

$2+\frac{4}{3}(x-1)+\frac{7}{18}(x-1)^2+\frac{8}{135}(x-1)^3+\cdots$.

Finally divide this by $(x-1)^2$ and you obtain the corresponding series.

The trick can be justified rigorously, but I don't have the time right now.

Hope this already answers your question.

Comment: BTW: such a series is called Laurent-series.